How do you solve this limit involving a sum?
The limit which I'm having trouble with is this: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$ I tried substituting the $n$ at the top of the sum with $\infty$ and then tried manipulating it to figure out, but I kept getting $0$ as the answer. This is what I tried to evaluate: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$The limit actually goes to $-1$ though instead of $0
$, but I'm confused as to how to do it. I believe there is a way where you substitute the entire limit with an integral of something like this: $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)dx$$ But I really want a method that doesn't use these pretty abstract methods to calculate, if there is a commonly known formula though that helps it simplify into this integral, that is OK.

$\sum ln k=\ln (n!)$. Use Stirlings formula.

See carefully that when $k=1$, then $\frac{k}{n}\to 0$ since $n\to \infty$. Again when $k=n$, then $\frac{k}{n}\to 1$. Now integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)dx$. You will get the answer.

I don't think that there is any other method for this according to the school level.

You can't naively just replace the upper bound of the sum with $\infty$, because there's an $n$ inside of the sum as well. You need to be a little more clever.
In this case, by using logarithm properties,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 n \ln \frac k n
= 
\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln \frac k n
= 
\frac 1 n \ln \left( \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} \right)
= 
\frac 1 n \ln \left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)
$$
The Stirling approximation tells us
$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n}
$$
so as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac 1 n \ln \left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)
\sim
\frac 1 n \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} \frac{n^n}{e^n}}{n^n} \right)
=
\frac 1 n \ln \left( \sqrt{2\pi n} e^{-n} \right)
=
\frac{\ln \sqrt{2\pi} + \ln \sqrt n + \ln e^{-n}}{n}
$$
Clearly,
$$
\frac{\ln \sqrt{2\pi}}{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
\qquad
\frac{\ln \sqrt n}{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
$$
leaving only
$$
\frac{\ln e^{-n}}{n} = \frac{-n}{n} = -1
$$
for the limit. Hence, we conclude that the limit is $-1$.

However, to be very frank, I would say that the Riemann sum approach is a lot less involved and straightforward (and not particularly abstract either). Since
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)
$$
where $\xi_i$ lie in the $i$th induced subinterval given by the partition of $[a,b]$ at $(n+1)$-equally spaced points, it is easy to see that, for your case,
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \ln(x) \\
\xi_k &= \frac k n, \text{ a right-endpoint evaluation rule} \\
b &= 1 \\
a &= 0
\end{align*}$$
and then compute $\int_0^1 \ln(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$, a trivial exercise with integration by parts.

Thank you for your answer. I still don't understand why I can't move in the limit to the inside and replace the n at the top with infinity, if the limit is already going to infinity in that way. I know it's awkward, but I still think it would work the same.

To make it easier, I always use $n!^{1/n}\approx \frac{n}{e}$.

As an alternative, avoiding Stirling approximation, by Stolz-Cesaro
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{(n+1)-n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=\ln\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\right]\to\ln \left(\frac1e\right)=-1$$

As an alternative, to avoid Stirling approximation, using that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 n \ln \frac k n
= \ln \left[\left( \frac{n!}{n^n} \right)^\frac1n\right]$$
since by ratio-root criterion
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \rightarrow L\implies a_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow L$$
in this case by $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$ we have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\to \frac1e \implies \ln \left(a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}\right) \to -1$$
